# Excel 2007: Intermittent 0xc0000005 crashes

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, crash

We are having an issue at the office I work. One of our users who has a workflow which consists mostly of Excel documents with dynamic formatting and macros which she uses to print building permits from. These documents were originally made in 2003 and when we made the switch over to 2007, maybe a couple years ago, no problems came about.

But over the last two months or so, she has been getting issues a couple times a day, at the very most, where Excel crashes upon trying to print the document. This loses her whole document and leaves a crash trace of `0xc0000005`. This does not happen all the time, in fact far from it. She can have whole days that go by with no issue and then a day where it happens three times. Here is an event viewer log for it:

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 12.0.6665.5003, time stamp: 0x5061d2a8
Faulting module name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 12.0.6665.5003, time stamp: 0x5061d2a8
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0013c909
Faulting process id: 0x930
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce0ad2e4b754ab
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\EXCEL.EXE
Report Id: c6d83227-76c6-11e2-b8a9-2c27d744856d
```

I've read many threads regarding this issue already but none of the solutions seem to have any affect. I'm making this thread as a last ditch effort to try to see if anyone knows the root cause of the issue - or if she is just going to have to redo these documents.

We have ensured that the problem is not PC based as she will get the issues on multiple computers. From what I can find of Microsoft's debug information, `Oxc0000005` comes up when an application tries to access nonpaged memory, or memory that has not been paged to it. I don't understand why this issue would only be happening some of the time if it was an issue to do with permissions though...

If you need any more information just let me know.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Office/Excel?

Comment: Many times, with no change

Comment: try this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/excel-2007-constantly-crashing/64cc057f-355a-41a7-83c5-7e6d9ca796a6

Comment: Appreciate the effort - but that was pretty much the first thing I tried with no dice.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, tried all the fixes from the web:

1. Disable/Remove add-ins
2. Remove ABBYY FineReader
3. Disable hardware acceleration
4. Check the file permissions on Ubuntu Samba Server

None of those worked.

And finally, the epiphany: **I turned off the preview pane in Windows Explorer and everything works fine.** Verified same behavior occurs on another computer on the network.

Answer (score -1):

I set the *compatibility mode* to that of Windows 7 for all users on the affected Office app.

This was done for Server 2008 R2; it should apply for Windows 8.1 too.