# Why does Excel 2016 (365) crash intermittently when a network file is open?

Tags: windows, shared-folders, microsoft-excel-2016

Excel 2016 is crashing on at least 3 computers when the user has a file open on the network.

There are several of these events on all affected computers:

```
Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.7167.2060, time stamp: 0x57cdbe01
Faulting module name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 16.0.7167.2060, time stamp: 0x57cdbe01
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x002be817
Faulting process id: 0x108c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d22313fcf5b04f
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
Report Id: 7b3fb31e-8f08-11e6-99c1-b8ac6f3e3f53
Faulting package full name: %14
Faulting package-relative application ID: %15
```

Here is what I have tried so far that did not work:

- Updating Office 2016 and Windows 7 to the latest version
- Repair installing Office 2016
- Disable windows preview pane (recommended by this post: [Excel 2007: Intermittent 0xc0000005 crashes](https://superuser.com/questions/587146/excel-2007-intermittent-0xc0000005-crashes))
- Searching for xls start, disabling compatibility mode, renaming the files, and editing the registry (as mentioned in this post: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_other/excel-2007-constantly-crashing/64cc057f-355a-41a7-83c5-7e6d9ca796a6)

Does anyone have a fix? I can provide additional information as necessary.

Thanks.